# Powershell Form Image Smooth Moving

Tags: forms, image, winforms, powershell, smooth-scrolling

I got a question about scripting in PowerShell.

Iam preparing "lottery application" in powershell for my family.
I want to have entire application in Windows Form and if possible, using only native functions (because after I would like to transfer it to *.exe)

I got an idea, that in form will be one static window (label appx. 50x50), where the "lottery numbers" will be switching.

Just exactly like on "slot machines"
https://www.casinorecenze.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/TurboGold-622x438.jpg

You got one static window, and symbols are smoothly switching under it.

I got label as a window and jpg as a lottery numbers (symbols)

```
# main label
$label2                                                 = New-Object 'Windows.Forms.Label'
$label2.Location                                        = '60, 65'
$label2.Size                                            = '100, 100'
$label2.BorderStyle                                     = '1'
$label2.Text                                            = ''
# roll image
# this image is 100x2000
$image                                                  = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$Global:scriptFolder\foo.jpg")
$label2.BackgroundImage                                 = $image
```

Problem is, that I don't know, how to make "move" with this image under label window. (load specific coordiations / part of image).

I appreciate any advice.

Marcel

Comment: Adding the code you are using will likely result in more answers. The question you are asking is confusing and it's hard to understand what you are asking without seeing what you are trying to do right now.

Comment: I will also point out that even though you are writing the code in powershell this isn't really a powershell specific question it is a Winforms question.